# Streaming a file with WCF: Do I need a checksum?

Tags: .net, wcf, streaming

Does streaming a file using WCF needs a checksum or the streaming process will detect lost packets and resend them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF usually goes over TCP which has built in checksumming and guarantees unmodified data delivery. That said the checksum is 32 bit long and might not detect every error by random chance. This does happen in practice (rarely).

The fact that TCP does not guarantee data integrity 100% is well known.

Whether you need your own checksumming depends on how much safety you need. If people die in case of corruption you better add a checksum indeed.

Comment: No one will die, that's for sure. I'll skip the checksum!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a multicast or unicast over UDP the underlying TCP connection should handle lost packets for you.